# How do I indent using PHP formatter in VS Code?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, format

I installed [phpfmt - PHP Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kokororin.vscode-phpfmt) on VS Code and currently have this configuration in `settings.json`

```
"[php]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "kokororin.vscode-phpfmt",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
},
"phpfmt.passes": [
    "AlignDoubleArrow",
    "AlignDoubleSlashComments",
    "AlignEquals",
    "OnlyOrderUseClauses",
    "AutoSemicolon",
    "IndentTernaryConditions",
    "ReindentAndAlignObjOps",
],
"phpfmt.enable_auto_align": true,
```

My problem is identation with arrows. For example, if I have code like this:

```
$market_data = DB::select('markets.public_id', 'radio_keywords.name radio_keyword')
                 ->from(Market::TABLE)
                 ->join(Radio::TABLE, [
                     'markets.radio_keyword_batch' => 'radio_keywords.batch',
                     'markets.id' => $market_id,
                 ])
                 ->one();
```

and if I save the file the code gets re-indented like this:

```
$market_data = DB::select('markets.public_id', 'radio_keywords.name radio_keyword')
    ->from(Market::TABLE)
    ->join(Radio::TABLE, [
        'markets.radio_keyword_batch' => 'radio_keywords.batch',
        'markets.id'                  => $market_id,
    ])
    ->one();
```

How can I keep the arrows aligned with the double colons?